# Multiple extensions for a VM with Azure ARM

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

We are configuring our VM with ARM. 
We use the DSC to install most of the requirements, however, installing the anti malware extension together with the DSC does not work.

We are getting the following error:
Multiple VMExtensions per handler not supported for OS type 'Windows'. VMExtension 'dscExtension' with handler 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC' already added or specified in input.

The resources look like this:

```
 {  
  "type":"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
  "name":"[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', 'antiMalwareExtension')]",
  "apiVersion":"[variables('api-version')]",
  "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
  "dependsOn":[  
     "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
  ],
  "properties":{  
     "publisher":"Microsoft.Azure.Security",
     "type":"IaaSAntimalware",
     "typeHandlerVersion":"1.1",
     "settings":{  
        "AntimalwareEnabled":"true",
        "Exclusions":{  
           "Paths":"C:\\Users",
           "Extensions":".txt",
           "Processes":"taskmgr.exe"
        },
        "RealtimeProtectionEnabled":"true",
        "ScheduledScanSettings":{  
           "isEnabled":"true",
           "scanType":"Quick",
           "day":"7",
           "time":"120"
        }
     },
     "protectedSettings":null
  }


},
{  
      "type":"Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions",
      "name":"[concat(variables('vmName'),'/', 'dscExtension')]",
      "apiVersion":"[variables('api-version')]",
      "location":"[resourceGroup().location]",
      "dependsOn":[  
         "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]"
      ],
      "properties":{  
         "publisher":"Microsoft.Powershell",
         "type":"DSC",
         "typeHandlerVersion":"2.9",
         "autoUpgradeMinorVersion":true,
         "settings":{  
            "ModulesUrl":"[parameters('dscLocation')]",
            "ConfigurationFunction":"[parameters('dscFunction')]",
            "Properties":{  
               "nodeName":"[variables('vmName')]"
            }
         }
      }
```

Comment: i find this a bit hard to believe, can you share the whole template?

Comment: There is nothing special in the template. The DSC resource alone works, but when adding the anti malware software, we get the error above...

Comment: try adding dependsOn to the DSC extension, so it waits for the antimalware extension to finish

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking to your template the 2 extensions are executed at the same time. Add a dependsOn to one of them:

```
  "dependsOn":[  
     "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'))]",
     "[concat('Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/', variables('vmName'),'/extensions/', 'antiMalwareExtension')]"
  ],
```

Comment: well, iaaSAntimalware isn't exactly dsc extension